# How do I create a window of decades using spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Sample Dataset :

```
1990;111;Tie Me Up! Tie Me Down!;Comedy;Banderas, Antonio;Abril, Victoria;Almod�var, Pedro;68;No;NicholasCage.png
1991;113;High Heels;Comedy;Bos�, Miguel;Abril, Victoria;Almod�var, Pedro;68;No;NicholasCage.png
1983;104;Dead Zone, The;Horror;Walken, Christopher;Adams, Brooke;Cronenberg, David;79;No;NicholasCage.png
1979;122;Cuba;Action;Connery, Sean;Adams, Brooke;Lester, Richard;6;No;seanConnery.png
1978;94;Days of Heaven;Drama;Gere, Richard;Adams, Brooke;Malick, Terrence;14;No;NicholasCage.png
1983;140;Octopussy;Action;Moore, Roger;Adams, Maud;Glen, John;68;No;NicholasCage.png
1984;101;Target Eagle;Action;Connors, Chuck;Adams, Maud;Loma, Jos� Antonio de la;14;No;NicholasCage.png
1989;99;American Angels: Baptism of Blood, The;Drama;Bergen, Robert D.;Adams, Trudy;Sebastian, Beverly;28;No;NicholasCage.png
```

Question: Here the column what I have is year, using this column I want to create a window of decades like 1990-2000,2000-2010 etc. I know there is a window function available for data-frame but I am not sure how do I create the window for 10 years(decade) each as a different bucket?

Window function for Reference: http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-two-part-5/

*Note: Looking for Scala based solutions*

Answer (score 1):

This link might help you.

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

You can create `WindowSpec` object and pass it to `range/rowsBetween` function.

I have a demo but for different example. Here it goes:

```
transactions.withColumn("column", transactions.col("cardNumber").over(Window.rowsBetween(x, y)))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but the year column is having multiple values for the same year so rowsBetween(1,10)  will not yield decade wise bucket and if I use range also I have to hard code the year range, hard coding will not work for other year ranges

Comment: That hard coding of year range can be replaced by a function call. Isn't it? May be using pattern-matching cases?

Comment: I found an alternative way and finding it more simpler to solve my use case.

Answer (score 0):

After a deep dive, I was able to split the data set into decade wise buckets with the help of below transformations

```
//Deriving new column named "Date" based on "year" column. This step is required to bucket the data set into decade wise buckets 
val MovieDFwithDate=SortedByYear.withColumn("Date",format_string(("01-01-%d"),$"year"))

//Casting string version of date to standard DATE object
val MovieDFwithDateFormat = MovieDFwithDate.withColumn("Date",to_date($"Date","MM-dd-yyyy"))

//Windowing the data set into decade buckets - 365 days * 10 years = 3650 days
val windowedDF = MovieDFwithDateFormat.select($"*",window($"Date","3650 days","3650 days"))
```